# Values undefined in React Hook Form

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

I have a form with React Hook Form, but all inputs send a undefined values.

This is the code of Form

```js
const {control,handleSubmit,register,formState:{errors}} = useForm();

const profile = async(data:any) => {
    console.log('Function profile',data)
}

<Controller
   control={control}
   rules={{
     required:false,
    }}
    name="name"       
    render={({field:{value,onChange}})=> (
       <View className="relative">
          <View className="absolute top-2 left-2 w-10 h-10 z-10">
              <AntDesign name="user" size={24} color="#D2D6DA"  />
           </View>
           <TextInput
             placeholder="Sue nome"
             className="border-[1px]"
             value={user?.name}
             onChangeText={onChange}
           />
       </View>
    )}
/>

<Button className="bg-azul-700 w-2/5 h-10 mb-6 mt-3" onPress={handleSubmit(profile)}>
    <Text className="text-white uppercase">
        EDITAR PERFIL
     </Text>
</Button>
```

But the result in console is

```
Function profile {"cpf": undefined, "email": undefined, "name": undefined, "senha": undefined, "senha_confimation": undefined}
```

Why the control don't get the value???.
The value of name has been {user.?name}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  <Controller
   control={control}
   rules={{
     required:false,
    }}
    name="name"       
    render={({field:{value,onChange}})=> (
       <View className="relative">
          <View className="absolute top-2 left-2 w-10 h-10 z-10">
              <AntDesign name="user" size={24} color="#D2D6DA"  />
           </View>
           <TextInput
             placeholder="Sue nome"
             className="border-[1px]"
             value={value} 
             onChangeText={onChange}
           />
       </View>
    )}
/>
```

=> if you want to fill the text input if some value use default values or setValue from react-hook-form

```
    const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
   
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: user?.name ?? '',     
    },
  });
```

by the way, your placeholder should be  placeholder="Seu nome" just a typing error